# reverse a stack and concatenate a popped stack

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

I'm trying to push any array list to a stack in reverse then concatenate a popped stacked. I getting the information from a file then storing it into an array List. Then i pushed the array List into a stack. now when i print the stack out its just printing the array List how can i pop the stack and concatenate it? here is my code so far

```
public static LinkedListStack myStack = new LinkedListStack();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    readFileLoadStack();
    popStackPrintMsg();
}

public static void readFileLoadStack()
{
  File afile;         // For file input
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // For file input
  String fileName;   // To hold a file name
  String line;
  ArrayList song = new ArrayList<>();
  boolean fileNotFound = true;

  do
  {
          // Get a file name from the user.
      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");
      fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
          // Attempt to open the file.
          try
          {
             afile = new File(fileName);
             Scanner inFile = new Scanner(afile);
             System.out.println("The file was found");
             fileNotFound = false;
             while (inFile.hasNextLine())
             {
                  song.add(line = inFile.next());
             }
             for(int i = 0; i < song.size(); i++)
                  {
                      myStack.push1(song);
                  }
          }
          catch (FileNotFoundException e)
          {
             fileNotFound = true;
          }
  } while (fileNotFound);
}
public static void popStackPrintMsg()
{
    if(!myStack.empty())
    {
        System.out.println(myStack.pop1());
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry stack is empty");
    }
}
```

output looks like this now :[Mary, had, a, little, lamb, Whose, fleece, was, white, as, snow, Everywhere, that, Mary, went, The, lamb, was, sure, to, go]

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

lamb little a had Mary

snow as white was fleece Whose

went Mary that Everywhere

go to sure was lamb The

i have made a custom class for the push and pop

```
{
   private Node first;

  /** 
     Constructs an empty stack.
  */
  public LinkedListStack()
  {  
     first = null;
  }

  /**
     Adds an element to the top of the stack.
     @param element the element to add
  */
  public void push1(Object element)
  {  
     Node newNode = new Node();
     newNode.data = element;
    newNode.next = first;
     first = newNode;
  }
   /**
     Removes the element from the top of the stack.
     @return the removed element
  */
  public Object pop1()
  {  
     if (first == null) { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
     Object element = first.data;
     first = first.next;
     return element;
  }

  /**
     Checks whether this stack is empty.
     @return true if the stack is empty
  */
  public boolean empty()
  {
     return first == null;
  }

  class Node
  {  
     public Object data;
     public Node next;
  }
```

}

Comment: Recommend formatting output as code or <pre>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problems in your code. Here is the working version along with some comments. This assumes the sentences in the file are separated by new lines and the words are separated by white spaces.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GeneralTest {
    //You want the same ordering for sentences. This collection
    //therefore should be a list (or a queue)
    //I have not changed the name so you can see how it makes a
    //difference
    public static List<LinkedListStack> myStack = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        readFileLoadStack();
        popStackPrintMsg();
    }

    public static void readFileLoadStack()
    {
        File afile;         // For file input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // For file input
        String fileName;   // To hold a file name
        String line;
        ArrayList song = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean fileNotFound = true;

        do
        {
            // Get a file name from the user.
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");
            fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
            // Attempt to open the file.
            try
            {
                afile = new File(fileName);
                Scanner inFile = new Scanner(afile);
                System.out.println("The file was found");
                fileNotFound = false;
                while (inFile.hasNextLine())
                {
                    //Here you need to use nextLine() instead of next()
                    song.add(inFile.nextLine());
                }

                //This loop is the main location your original code goes wrong
                //You need to create a stack for each sentence and add it to the
                //list. myStack will hold a list of stacks after this loop is done
                for(int i = 0; i < song.size(); i++)
                {
                    String songString = (String) song.get(i);
                    String[] sga = songString.split(" ");
                    LinkedListStack rowStack = new LinkedListStack();
                    for(int j=0; j < sga.length; j++) rowStack.push1(sga[j]);
                    myStack.add(rowStack);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                fileNotFound = true;
            }
        } while (fileNotFound);
    }
    public static void popStackPrintMsg()
    {

        //To get all values in a collection you need to
        //loop over it. A single if will not work
        for(LinkedListStack rs : myStack)
        {
            //Each entry in the list is a LinkedListStack
            //So you can pop them and print the results with
            //appropriate separators
            while(!rs.empty())
                System.out.print(rs.pop1() + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, your code has many other problems. For example, you really should use generics when you create a collection class.

The main problem with your code is that to produce the output you have described, you will need a **queue of stacks**. I have implemented the concept using `ArrayList` to show the source of the problem. But if you want to learn data structures (or if this is a homework problem), then you should try implementing and using a queue as well.